# HtmlAgilityPack can't detect div

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to retrieve data from a website. But I'm getting an error.

My Code;

```
  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(contents);
        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("(//div[@class='table table-striped table-hover animated zoomIn faster']//text()[normalize-space()])[last()]");
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```

help picture:

[image]

I get an error when I want to get the numbers I show in the picture.
what do I have to do to get it?

Comment: looks like you are looking for `table` and `td` elements, not a div.

Comment: can you write sample code?

Comment: Please provide code as text, not as a picture of text. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask] before asking a question.

Comment: <table id="leaders-generaltable" class="table table-striped table-hover animated zoomIn faster"> <thead>

/

<td align="center">1.848</td>

x path : //*[@id="leaders-generaltable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]